# Equivalence class of quadratic forms

Tags: number-theory

There is a natural action of the Hecke modular group ([cf wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_congruence_subgroup#principal_congruence_subgroup)) $\Gamma_0(q)$ on the set of integral quadratic forms $\phi = aX^2 + bXY + cY^2$ of discriminant $\Delta$ such that $a \equiv 0 \pmod q$.

I have two questions :

- is there an explicit description of the equivalence classes when $\Delta = 0$ or $\Delta = k^2 > 0$ ?
- When $\Delta > 0$ is not a square, is it true that each stabilizer is nontrivial (hence infinite cyclic) ?

I'm especially interested in references on this kind of question (equivalence classes of quadratic forms modulo a conguence subgroup), even if it does not explicitly answer my questions. Thanks !